# ReactJS Function Components object updates on second time

Tags: reactjs

I have a login page(Functional Component), When a user tries to login without entering the required fields, I have to show the error message(ex:"Email is required"). When an invalid field exists, I shouldn't make the API call.

But, without entering fields, when I click on login button, API call is done. Again clicking on login button stops the API call.

I have made this demo - https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-pd6vvk?file=login.js which explains the issue.

Steps to follow:

1.Click on login without filling any text values. You can see "API request made" statement when fields are invalid.

2.Again click on login button, "API Request stopped" statement is displayed now.

I am new to React and I don't know, the reason and the solution to fix this issue.

Can somebody please help me out?

Thank you,

Abhilash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because, `setValidFields` has async behaviour :

```
validateLoginForm(); //<--- inside this setValidFieldsis async
console.log(validFields);
if (isFormValid()) { //<---- so,this will still have true value ( means not updated )
```

```
// inside validateLoginForm()
// this state change won,t be reflected immediately
setValidFields(validFields => ({
    ...validFields,
    [key]: error.length == 0
}));
```

I have made few changes as per your code structure, as long as I know you will need `useEffect` also as shown in working demo.

**[WORKING DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-react-61725244?file=login.js)**

Comment: I will look about `useEffect` event. Thank you for the quick reply vivek.